# How can I resubmit Oozi Coordinator by changing the start and end date?

Tags: oozie-coordinator

Is there any way to **resubmit coordinator** of Oozie in *hue*?

I have one coordinator that run everyday from 1-1-2016 to 30-1-2016.

Now, I want to change date dynamically from 1-2-2016 to 28-2-2016.

Is there any way to dynamically change start and end date without stopping the coordinator to throw Java code or any other way?

The following is my Java code, but it is not working - PUT Request gives me an error

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

public class JobSchedule {
    public static void main(String arg[]) throws Exception {

        // oozie.coord.application.path
        // hdfs://nameservice1/user/hue/oozie/workspaces/hue-oozie-1464585998.59

        // String GetData =
        // "curl -XGET http://localhost:11000/oozie/v2/job/0021784-160502160551671-oozie-oozi-C?show=info&timezone=UTC";
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        String request = "http://localhost:11000/oozie/v2/job/0023481-160502160551671-oozie-oozi-C?show=info&timezone=UTC";
        URL url = new URL(request);
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
        Date End = null;
        Date start = null;
        try {
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
            // connection.setUseCaches(false);
            Gson gson = new Gson();

            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            osw.write(request);
            osw.flush();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

            String line = "";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                output.append(line + "\n");
            }

            osw.close();
            reader.close();
            JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) gson.fromJson(output.toString(), JsonObject.class);
            String Ed = jsonObject.get("endTime").toString();
            End = new Date(Ed);
            String Sd = jsonObject.get("startTime").toString();
            start = new Date(Sd);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        connection.disconnect();

        String Data = null;

        Calendar sc = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'00:00:ss.SSSzzz");
        sc.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        sf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        String strt = sf.format(sc.getTime());
        // TimeZone utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
        // sf.setTimeZone(utc);
        // Date d=new Date(sf.format(sc.getTime()));
        System.out.println("Start Date :" + strt);
        SimpleDateFormat sf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSzzz");

        Calendar ec = Calendar.getInstance();
        ec.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, ec.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        String end = sf1.format(ec.getTime());
        System.out.println("End Date :" + end);
        // Data =
        // "PUT /oozie/v2/job/0023481-160502160551671-oozie-oozi-C?action=coord-rerun&type="
        // + strt + "::" + end + "&scope=&refresh=false&nocleanup=false";
        if (End.before(new Date()) == true) {

            URL url1 = null;
            try {
                url1 = new URL("http:localhost:11000/oozie/v2/job/0023481-160502160551671-oozie-oozi-C?action=coord-rerun&type=date" + strt + "::" + end + "&scope=&refresh=false&nocleanup=false");
                HttpURLConnection hurl = (HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();
                hurl.setRequestMethod("PUT");
                hurl.setDoOutput(true);
                // hurl.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

                // String payload = "";

                // OutputStreamWriter os = new
                // OutputStreamWriter(hurl.getOutputStream());
                // os.write();
                // os.flush();
                // os.close();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // connection.setUseCaches(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to change some parameters of your coordinator by using following argument "change" with argument "value".

```
oozie job -oozie http://$oozie_path/oozie -change $oozie_coorinator_id -value endtime=$new_timestamp
```

With value, you can pass following arguments:

**endtime:** the end time of the coordinator job.
**concurrency:** the concurrency of the coordinator job.
**pausetime:** the pause time of the coordinator job.
**status:** new status for coordinator job.

However, it seems that it is not possible to modify start time. The best approach would be to stop the current coordinator and launch it again with right values.

source: https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.1.0/DG_CommandLineTool.html#Changing_endtimeconcurrencypausetimestatus_of_a_Coordinator_Job 
(Changing endtime/concurrency/pausetime/status of a Coordinator Job)

Comment: Thank you sir . It is Helpful solution but i want to do dynamically throw JAVA API . what i need to do is to run only java code and it will rerun the Coordinator with new values.So is there any Solution??